# Событие .click() срабатывает в двух разных методах одновременно

Tags: javascript, jquery, client

Здравствуйте! Пишу клиент на js для своего api на php. Оговорюсь сразу, я с js только начала работать, могут быть ошибки, которые я просто не заметила.

Суть такова. У меня есть клиент, который выводит список статей из api в виде таблицы. Для каждой записи таблицы доступно обновление и удаление. Также есть возможность добавить свою статью в таблицу.

Для создания и редактирования статьи я использую одну и ту же форму.

Код формы (*форма для добавление.редактирования статей имеет id = addArcticle*):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>JS-client</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" id="newArticle" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="articles.addAction()">Add new article</button>
      </nav>
        <form id="addArcticle" class="col-lg-2">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Add new article</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title">Title of article</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <label for="exampleTextarea">Content</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="content" rows="3"></textarea>
              </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="author">Author</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="author">
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Add</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/client.js"></script>
        <script src="js/helpers.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Если стоит задача **добавить новую статью** в таблицу, то я нажимаю на кнопку *Add new article* и у меня появляется эта форма. До нажатия на кнопку, форма скрыта методом jQuery hide().

Добавление новой записи проходит хорошо. 
Но, если я пытаюсь без перезагрузки страницы сразу нажать кнопку **редактировать**, то, кроме того, что данная запись изменяется, создается еще и новая такая же запись. Т.е. событие click() срабатывает в двух разных методах.

Вот как я обрабатываю данную форму методами js:

```
function ArticleController() {
    this.posts = [];

    this.indexAction = function() {
        articles.getAllArticles();
    };

    this.addAction = function() {
        $('#articleTable').hide();
        $('#addArcticle').show();

        $('#add').click(function(){
            title = $('#title').val();
            content = $('#content').val();
            author = $('#author').val();
            articles.addArticle(title, content, author);
        });
    };

    this.deleteAction = function(id) {
        this.deleteArticle(id);
    };

    this.editAction = function(id) {
        var article = document.getElementById(''+id);

        $('#title').val("" + article.cells[1].innerHTML);
        $('#content').val("" + article.cells[2].innerHTML);
        $('#author').val("" + article.cells[3].innerHTML);

        $('#add').click(function(){
            title = $('#title').val();
            content = $('#content').val();
            author = $('#author').val();
            articles.editArticle(id, title, content, author);
        });
    };
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка.

Вот вид самого клиента для ориентации где какая кнопка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что Вы навешиваете два разных обработчика (больше, но об этом - ниже) на кнопку с `id="add"`. Обработчик должен быть один, а внутри него - логика поведения для создания и редактирования. К моменту вызова обработчика должно быть известно, какая операция сейчас выполняется.

Или заведите две разные кнопки с разными обработчиками - для добавления и редактирoвания, и показывайте/прячьте их в зависимости от ситуации.

Теперь о "больше обработчиков".

Каждый раз, когда вызываются `ArticleController.addAction` и `ArticleController.editAction`, код добавляет новые обработчики к `$('#add').click(`. Эти накопившиеся обработчики будут все выстреливать по нажатию на кнопку.

Подозреваю, что объект `ArticleController` - один на странице. Навешивайте обработчик клика на кнопку один раз - в конструкторе.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Скажите, пожалуйста, насчет вашей фразы "Навешивайте обработчик клика на кнопку один раз - в конструкторе." - это имеется в виду в каком-то одном методе или addAction или editAction? Я просто не совсем понимаю.

Comment: @kittycat_13 "В конструкторе" - значит прямо в функции `function ArticleController() {`, не в `this.addAction = function() {` или `this.editAction = function(id) {`. Если Вам нужно хранить идентификатор статьи в промежуткe времени между показом формы и нажатием на кнопку в ней (например, при редактировании) заведите для этого поле в `ArticleController`.